# Trying To Post Via Button

Tags: php, html

I Have tried many solutions posted on stack overflow and non of them have worked.

It could just be me but i tried it on a separate file and it worked but if i use my current site with nice css it won't work

I Have tried the exact code on [LAEPHP](http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/How-to-check-if-the-submit-button-is-clicked-in-PHP.php) and it worked but when i added my code as you can see below it does not display anything when the button is clicked and it does not even refresh the page on click

```php
<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Username</label>
        <input class="au-input au-input--full" type="email" name="target" placeholder="Example">
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label>API key</label>
        <input class="au-input au-input--full" type="text" name="key" placeholder="X7UI-9H2D-IZAS">
    </div>

    <?php

        $key= $_POST['key'];
        $send= $_POST['send'];

        if ($send) {
            if (!empty($key)) {
                echo 'The key you entered is ' . $key;
            }
            else {
                echo 'You did not enter a key. Please enter a key into this form field.';
            }
        }
    ?>

    <button class="subscribe btn btn-primary btn-block" name="send" type="submit">Check Key</button>
</form>
```

Comment: "it won't work" doesn't tell us anything.  What specifically doesn't work?  _In what way_ doesn't it work?  What _does_ happen?  What is the _expected_ behavior?  What debugging have you done?  If you are getting errors, what are the exact error messages?

Comment: No Error messages. No Error log file made. The Code ```   $key= $_POST['key'];
                            $send= $_POST['send'];

                            if ($send){
                            if (!empty($key)) {
                            echo 'The key you entered is ' . $key;
                            }
                            else {
                            echo 'You did not enter a key. Please enter a key into this form field.';
                            }
                            }
                            ?> ``` Works But not in my case.

Comment: It Simply does not return anything its like clicking a useless button. But the code on this site http://www.learningaboutelectronics.com/Articles/How-to-check-if-the-submit-button-is-clicked-in-PHP.php works. I have even tried it on my server and i don't get a response at all.

Comment: So you click on the button and literally nothing happens? It won't even refresh the page?

Comment: Nope the page will not refresh on button click.

Comment: Can you please update your question to be as the form you have? You've split the html into different code blocks in your question. Btw. do you have any javascript that listens to the submit or button click event?

Comment: If the form doesn't even submit at all, then check your browser's Javascript console.  Also, you say you're not seeing errors, but you most definitely should be getting undefined index errors due to the fact that you're executing your PHP both on the initial page load and on the submit.  Something's not adding up here.

Comment: I do not have any js on the site just php and html. i have updated my question and code blocks

Comment: Patrick thats what i thought. i rarely run into errors and the most simple thing has me stuck. I Will retry and post back

Comment: I think it does submit, but does it quickly. The issue as I can see it, is that you're checking if the button is sent and isn't "falsy". Since you don't have a value on the button, it will be an empty string which will make `if ($send)` to evaluate as "false". Try and add `value="send"` to the button or change your check to: `if (isset($_POST['send']))`. You should also not do `$key = $_POST['key'];` before checking if the key exists.

Comment: Thank you everyone. The solution that worked was from Magnus. Thanks for the help. Sorry for my wording

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I see is that you're checking if the button was sent and isn't "falsy". Since you don't have a `value`-attribute on the button, it will be an empty string, which is a "falsy" value, meaning that the first `if`-statement will never evaluate as true.

Try changing your code to:

```
<?php
// isset() is better since it check if the key exists and isn't null.
if (isset($_POST['send'])) {
    // If you rather put the values in separate variables,
    // you should do it here, inside the if-statement (where we know we
    // got a POST request)

    if (!empty($_POST['key'])) {
        echo 'The key you entered is ' . $_POST['key'];
    }
    else {
        echo 'You did not enter a key. Please enter a key into this form field.';
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `$send` is `null` when the form is being sent to the browser and an empty string (`""`") when the browser is posting the form. In PHP, when converted to a boolean (as in your `if ($send)` statement), both of these evaluate to false and the code inside the `if` statement doesn't run.

The quick fix would be to change it to:

```php
if ($send !== null) // the `!==` is for preventing the type juggling that `!=` does
```

However, a better method is to use the `isset()` function which checks if a variable or key in an array exists like so:

```php
if (isset($_POST['send']))
```

If you were to enable full error reporting, you may get some notices that the `$_POST['key']` and `$_POST['send']` variables don't exist. With my recommendation that uses `isset()`, you won't need the `$send` variable anymore, and the other notice will go away if assign the value to the `$key` variable after you check that the `$_POST['send']` variable is set.